# Can't access file from another installation of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, multi-boot

A while back my laptop stopped booting into Windows 7 and instead constantly loaded a blue screen of death. So I installed another copy of Windows 7 and opted to keep the installation of the original copy of Windows 7 intact. (On the boot menu both Win installs are listed). The new installation works fine however I am unable to find my documents on the older Windows installation. I have two Hard Drives listed C: (30.3 GB) and D: (252 GB) both on the same physical drive. If I remember correctly a new partition was created for the latest installation of Windows. The Winodws.old folder exists on the C: drive, however it is empty. I was very careful to make sure that all older files would stay intact during the installation.

Is there a way to retrieve these files from the new installation? If not, perhaps I could boot into the older version and circumvent the blue screen?

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the C: drive in My Computer, Properties>Tools>ErrorChecking. Tick both boxes and select "Check now"

[image]

This will perform a low-key disk recovery, which should work.

Comment: This did not recover the files.

Comment: @Jason: OK, generally it works in such situations. The next step is [trying to recover the partition with stronger tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OdUVVLvRBY). If that doesn't work, you probably have to give it to data recovery experts.